# Check if lookup field is not null in Process Builder

Tags: process-builder, flow

I'm trying to define some criteria in process builder that checks to see if a user was selected in an Assign to User custom lookup field. However, process builder won't let me select that field for the criteria. I am required to traverse the lookup field and select a field on the user object. Is there a way around that? I just need to check if that field != null.

[image: Set Conditions Screen]

[image]

Comment: Can you explain your problem briefly..@Allen Mann

Comment: I have a Quick Action for Case Feed that has an Assign to User field. It is a lookup field to Users. So, in process builder I need to define criteria for the action. If Assign_to_User__c != null I want to continue the process. But I do not see a way to just select that field, I am required to use "Assign to User >" like shown in my screenshot above.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of using the `Conditions are met` you could use `Formula evaluates to true` and use a formula to determine if it has a value.

[image]

Comment: Ya it works definitely and my suggestion is instead of using ISNULL use ISBLANK  @Allen Mann

Answer (score 3):

I was able to make the `not null` check by using $GlobalConstant.Null when the Type is set to Global Constant.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to scroll down a little bit and you will find the field Assign to user.

What you are seeing in image is relationship field.

Comment: I thought the same, but it's not there.

Comment: it must be there, try to type 'assign' in the search box

Comment: Updated post with screenshot of available fields searching for "assign". Still nothing =(

Comment: Strange, I am not very sure will it help or not, can you double check what is the label and API name of the field?

Comment: What @C0DEPirate suggests, please also see https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000DfGAAA0 You must search for the API name, not the label. A known bug/feature.