# Check Parent Is Available before accessing in Process Builder Formula

Tags: formula, process-builder, visual-workflow, exception

Process builder bombs if you try and access a value on a parent relationship record on a record without a value for the parent relationship. For criteria this is easy to avoid by first checking that the lookup is not equal to null (see [Check if lookup field is not null in Process Builder](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/120865/check-if-lookup-field-is-not-null-in-process-builder))

But, this doesn't seem to work in formulas. I've got the following

```
ISPICKVAL([CampaignMember].Status, 'Responded') &&
NOT(ISBLANK([CampaignMember].LeadId)) &&
NOT(ISPICKVAL([CampaignMember].Lead.Status , 'New')) &&
OR(
 CONTAINS(LOWER([CampaignMember].Campaign.Name),'Name1'),
 CONTAINS(LOWER([CampaignMember].Campaign.Name),'Name2'),
 CONTAINS(LOWER([CampaignMember].Campaign.Name),'Name3')
)
```

If I update a campaign member that's related to a contact (and hence `[CampaignMember].Lead` is null) I get the following error

> The flow failed to access the value for myVariable_current.Lead.Status
>   because it hasn't been set or assigned.

However, I thought this wouldn't happen since `NOT(ISBLANK([CampaignMember].LeadId))` is evaluated before `NOT(ISPICKVAL([CampaignMember].Lead.Status , 'New'))`.

I've tried using `ISNULL` as well with the same the same result. Now, I'm stuck, what's the proper way to access `[CampaignMember].Lead.Status` to avoid issues with null lead lookups?

Comment: I recommend you be more consistent and use `AND` rather than `&&` (since you already use `OR` over `||`). Doubt it would solve your issue but I find it easier to read (and somewhat advantageous to be more obviously distinct from code syntax).

Comment: @AdrianLarson i think i'm going need a vote on the question before getting code style advice ;-)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally, Process Builder *does* do short-circuit evaluation on Boolean expressions, so this is an effective way to guard against `null` references.

I tried to reduce this to a minimal example, and the issue appears to be that the `ISPICKVAL()` function is evaluated before Boolean short-circuiting.

A Process Builder with this formula-based condition works correctly when inserting a Campaign Member with a blank Lead lookup:

```
NOT(ISBLANK([CampaignMember].LeadId)) && [CampaignMember].Lead.LastName = "Test"
```

while this one fails:

```
NOT(ISBLANK([CampaignMember].LeadId)) && ISPICKVAL([CampaignMember].Lead.Status, "Test")
```

The same is true of using the `TEXT()` formula against `Lead.Status`; the formula function is evaluated first, resulting in the null exception.

One workaround is to create a Text field `Status_Text__c` on Lead, whose value is `TEXT(Status)`. Your formula can then evaluate the field without calling a formula function in Process Builder:

```
NOT(ISBLANK([CampaignMember].LeadId)) && [CampaignMember].Lead.Status_Text__c = "Test"
```

(I confirmed that this works; this is a wrinkle to Process Builder evaluation I hadn't met before).

Comment: process builder never ceases to surprise with special edge cases, kudos for the fine research!!